# Partition a set into all possible subsets that are included in given list

Tags: java, subset, partitioning

Given a list of specific subsets like

```
S = [ {1}, {2}, {2, 3}, {3}, {4} ]
```

and a "universe" set like

```
U = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

I need a java function that finds all the possible partitions of U made of sets from S? With this example, such partitions include:

```
{1} {2} {3} {4}

{1} {2, 3} {4}
```

etc..

I found a similar example that founds all the possible partitions of a set and I adjust it to keep only those partitions that includes the given subsets, but given a "Universe" set of 10 or more numbers, it becomes very slow (too many possibilities). Here is my code

```
private List<List<List<Integer>>> buildFullPartitions(List<Integer> inputSet, List<List<Integer>> subsets)
{
    List<List<List<Integer>>> partitions = new ArrayList<>();
    if (inputSet.isEmpty()) {
        List<List<Integer>> empty = new ArrayList<>();
        partitions.add(empty);

        return partitions;
    }

    int limit = 1 << (inputSet.size() - 1);

    for(int j = 0; j < limit; ++j) {
        List<List<Integer>> parts = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> part1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> part2 = new ArrayList<>();
        parts.add(part1);
        parts.add(part2);
        int i = j;

        for(int item : inputSet) {
            parts.get(i&1).add(item);
            i >>= 1;
        }

        for(List<List<Integer>> b : buildFullPartitions(part2))
        {
            List<List<Integer>> holder = new ArrayList<>();
            holder.add(part1);
            holder.addAll(b);

            int matchedParts = 0;
            for(List<Integer> particle : holder) {
                for(List<Integer> subset : subsets) {
                    if(particle.equals(subset))) {
                        matchedParts++;
                    }
                }

                if(matchedParts == holder.size())
                    partitions.add(holder);
            }
        }
    }

    return partitions;
}
```

Any suggestion on how improve that by not looking for all the possible partitions but only those which contains only the given subsets?

In response to comments I edited my code to be more clear what I am doing.
I profile my code and with different "universe" sets of different length and the results are:

- 12 length  --->  30 seconds
- 13 length  --->  208 seconds
  and that number grows geometrical

Comment: 1) The interesting parts are not included in your question: `buildFullPartitions`, `CompoundTable`, `intArrayToList`. 2) Did you profile your code?

Comment: Since you want to improve working code, isn't this a question better asked at [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: intArrayToList is a custom function that makes an int[] array into a ArrayList<Integer>
-- CompoundTable contains the subsets of interest
-- buildFullPartitions is a recursive call to the same function